# R code for reading tabular data files and plotting light curves of modeled stars

Tags: r

Here is a minimal example of my task...

I have four 2-column files. `profile1.data`

```
  zone luminosity
1     1   1359.019
2     2   1359.030
3     3   1359.009
4     4   1358.988
5     5   1358.969
6     6   1358.951
7     7   1358.934
8     8   1358.917
9     9   1358.899
10   10   1358.881
```

`profile2.data`

```
   zone luminosity
1     1   1357.336
2     2   1357.352
3     3   1357.332
4     4   1357.310
5     5   1357.289
6     6   1357.270
7     7   1357.252
8     8   1357.233
9     9   1357.214
10   10   1357.194
```

`profile3.data`

```
   zone luminosity
1     1   1355.667
2     2   1355.687
3     3   1355.667
4     4   1355.644
5     5   1355.622
6     6   1355.602
7     7   1355.582
8     8   1355.562
9     9   1355.541
10   10   1355.520
```

`profile4.data`

```
   zone luminosity
1     1   1354.008
2     2   1354.032
3     3   1354.013
4     4   1353.990
5     5   1353.967
6     6   1353.945
7     7   1353.923
8     8   1353.902
9     9   1353.879
10   10   1353.857
```

I also have a vector named `phases`. There is one `phase` value for each `profile.data`

```
 rsp_phase1  rsp_phase2  rsp_phase3  rsp_phase4 
0.002935897 0.004602563 0.006269230 0.007935897
```

Finally, there are profile files for one of FOUR sets labeled A to D. The set directories are named `LOGS_A1a`, `LOGS_B1a`, etc. and contains the profile files, a file named `history.data` which contains `phase` values, and a `profile.index` file that states how many profiles there are in the directory. The sets do NOT have the same number of profiles.

What I am doing with this data is plotting luminosity vs phase for each zone, and putting one each of the four plots for each set on one canvas altogether.

[image: Example of plot with a subplot for each set]

For example, to create a luminosity vs phase plot of the first zone, I grab the luminosity value from every profile in the directory at zone 1. This is my first plot. Then I do the same for the other zones. At the moment, I am accomplishing this through for loops in R.

```
for (zone_num in 1:10){
  
  png(file.path(paste("Light_Curve_","Zone_",zone_num,".png",sep="")), 
      width = 1200, height = 960)
  par(mar=c(5,4,4,2) + 2) 
  
  luminosities <- c()
  
  for (prof_num in 1:4) {
    
    prof.path <- file.path('LOGS_A1a', paste0('profile', prof_num, '.data'))
    if (!file.exists(prof.path)) next
    #print(prof.path)
    DF.profile <- read.table(prof.path, header=1, skip=5)
    
    luminosity <- DF.profile$luminosity[zone_num]
    luminosities <- c(luminosities, luminosity)
    
  }
  
  plot.table <- data.frame(phases, luminosities)
  o <- order(phases)
  
  with(plot.table, plot(x=phases[o], y=luminosities[o],
                        main=paste("Zone",zone_num,"Light Curve",sep=" "),
                        type="l", pch=3, lwd = 6, col="purple", xlab=expression("Phase"),
                        ylab=expression("Luminosity " (L/L['\u0298'])), cex.main=1.60,
                        cex.lab=1.80, cex.axis=1.60))
  dev.off()
}
```

As you will realize, it seems that the biggest problem is that I am repeatedly reading the same files into R. This should be done once separately. Is there a way to avoid this and speed it up?

Comment: I have rolled back the code changes in revision 2. After receiving an answer you are not allowed to update the code in your question. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for minimal code changes:

```
prof_num <- 1:4
prof.path <- file.path('LOGS_A1a', paste0('profile', prof_num, '.data'))
DF.profile <- lapply(prof.path, function(x) read.table(x, header = 1, skip = 5))

for (zone_num in 1:10) {
  
  png(file.path(paste("Light_Curve_","Zone_",zone_num,".png",sep = "")), 
      width = 1200, height = 960)
  par(mar = c(5,4,4,2) + 2) 
  
  luminosities <- c()
  for (prof_num in 1:4) {
    luminosity <- DF.profile[[prof_num]]$luminosity[zone_num]
    luminosities <- c(luminosities, luminosity)
  }
  
  plot.table <- data.frame(phases, luminosities)
  o <- order(phases)
  
  with(plot.table, plot(x=phases[o], y=luminosities[o],
                        main=paste("Zone",zone_num,"Light Curve",sep=" "),
                        type="l", pch=3, lwd = 6, col="purple", xlab=expression("Phase"),
                        ylab=expression("Luminosity " (L/L['\u0298'])), cex.main=1.60,
                        cex.lab=1.80, cex.axis=1.60))
  dev.off()
}
```

I already answered this question... where did it disappear?

Comment: Why is `prof_num <- 1:4` defined in the first line?

Comment: @Woj why not? because in third line we read the data... it is the same variable as in your code... it shows file nr that needs to be read.

Comment: Understood. Also, the original post was deleted because although your solution speeds up the creation of one plot, it did not speed up the creation of the 2x2 plots I am actually creating for my task, but actually slowed it down. I am reading these profiles across 4 `sets <- c('A','B','C','D'), with each set's directory NOT having the same number of profiles. I was not sure how to convey the issue in a minimal example like the one above so the example assumes one set, but should I edit my post to show what I mean?

Comment: @Woj if you change the directories and read each time different datasets, then yes, you should specify that in question. Also, in that case, I think there will be hard to find improvements...

Comment: I've edited my question. I am not sure if I should include the entire compressed data (the compressed `LOGS` directories that I explain in the post) for clarity, or if I should subset all the files to keep a minimal example at the expense of clarity. But please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: @Woj it looks that you can use my answer inside your loop. `prof_num <- prof.idx$prof_num`

Comment: @Woj look into faster functions for reading data, for example, `data.table`s `fread`

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean I can paste `prof_num <- 1:4` and the other two lines in the profile loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127490/discussion-between-minem-and-woj).